# Prove Every Function is a Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

In my notes my professor has a question to prove that $\forall m,n \in \Bbb N^+$, $2^{mn}\ge n^m$.

There is a suggestion that it can be proved by taking the logarithm of the inequality so that $mn \ge m\cdot \log_2(n)$ but he said it is a more preferable proof to show that every function is a relation. How might the proof work out to show that every function is a relation?

Comment: Functions are particular cases of binary relations. There is nothing to prove, it follows from the definition of function. **Edit:** I find the given hint unhelpful. I'd prove it by induction.

Answer (score 3):

Notice $a^x \geq 1 $ for $a \geq 1 $. If we put $a = \frac{2^n}{n}$ and $x = m $, then

$$ \left( \frac{2^n}{n} \right)^m \geq 1 \iff 2^{mn} \geq n^m$$